# comparing 2 lists of objects and return changes in the new list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a web app that gives users a feature to update (no delete or add) multiple records on the same page. As users submit changes, I pull the original list from the database and use linq to compare it to the updated list. Any changed records will be put on a new list and send to database for update.
Below is my code to compare. As I debug, I can see the 2 lists are different but the code returns the Differences with comparer = null, first = null, second = null. Can you guys spot the bug?

```
var Differences = OriginalList.Where(x => !NewList.Any(x1 => x1.ServiceName == x.ServiceName
                                                        && x1.ServiceDescription == x.ServiceDescription
                                                        && x1.ServiceURL == x.ServiceURL
                                                        && x1.OrderIndex == x.OrderIndex
                                                        && x1.GroupID == x.GroupID
                                                        && x1.Active == x.Active))
        .Union(NewList.Where(x => !OriginalList.Any(x1 => x1.ServiceName == x.ServiceName
                                                        && x1.ServiceDescription == x.ServiceDescription
                                                        && x1.ServiceURL == x.ServiceURL
                                                        && x1.OrderIndex == x.OrderIndex
                                                        && x1.GroupID == x.GroupID
                                                        && x1.Active == x.Active)));

return Differences;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the Linq Except method to figure out the differences? There's an overload to specify how to compare the object equality (or you can override Equals on the object behind x1).

Comment: The reason is I have become incompetent. I have gotten a bad habit not to go to the tested codes to make changes for the better. Thanks for the tip, mate.

Comment: Ah. I think we've all been there. If I had a dime for every time I wrote something I thought was clever, only to find it was better implemented somewhere in the actual frame work.. I'd have a lot of dimes... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for Linq's Except method.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx

You'll need to define how to compare for equality of your "x1" object.  Probably the easiest way to do that is to override `Equals()`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Then to get the difference, you simply do:

```
var Differences = OriginalList.Except(NewList);
```